# How do I add a tuple to an existing one, and make it nested?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nested, tuples

I'm new to coding.

The exercise is:

"*The function gets 2 elements as parameters of the 'tuple' type.*
*The function returns a tuple containing all of the **pairs** that can be created from the tuple elements, that have been sent as arguments.*

**Example:**

```
first_tuple = (1, 2, 3)
second_tuple = (4, 5, 6)
mult_tuple(first_tuple, second_tuple)
```

**Correct Result:**

```
((1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6), (2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6), (3, 4), (3, 5), (3, 6), (4, 1), (5, 1), (6, 1), (4, 2), (5, 2), (6, 2), (4, 3), (5, 3), (6, 3))
```

This is my code:

```
def mult_tuple(tuple1, tuple2):
    new_tuple = ()

    for i in list(tuple1):
        for j in list(tuple2):
            temp_tuple = (i, j)
            new_tuple = new_tuple + (temp_tuple, )

    for i in list(tuple1):
        for j in list(tuple2):
            temp_tuple = (j, i)
            new_tuple = new_tuple + (temp_tuple, )

    return new_tuple
```

My question is, why only when I do: `new_tuple = new_tuple + (temp_tuple, )` it returns the right result, and when I do: `new_tuple = new_tuple + temp_tuple` (With out the brackets on the temp_tuple), **it returns an unested tuple**?

**Wrong result for example:**

```
(1, 4, 1, 5, 1, 6, 2, 4, 2, 5, 2, 6, 3, 4, 3, 5, 3, 6, 4, 1, 5, 1, 6, 1, 4, 2, 5, 2, 6, 2, 4, 3, 5, 3, 6, 3)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python when you use the + operator with two tuples, it appends the elements of the second tuple to the end of the first tuple.

```
>>> ('a','b') + ('c','d')
('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
```

When you instead try to add (temp_tuple, ) to new_tuple, what you are actually doing is creating a new tuple with temp_tuple as its only element, so when you append this new tuple it is going to add its only element which is a tuple to the end of new_tuple.

```
>>> ('a','b') + (('c','d'), )
('a', 'b', ('c', 'd'))
```

In this example the second tuple only has ('c','d') as its only element, so it naturally gets added to the end of ('a', 'b').